# Is there an easy way to do a simple file upload using Node/PostgreSQL for any type of file?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, file-upload

I want to store files in an existing postgreSQL database by uploading them by means of an express server.

The file comes into the POST end point like this:

```
{ name: 'New Data.xlsx',
  data: <Buffer 50 4c 03 04 14 01 06 00 08 00 00 24 21 00 1f 0a 93 21 cf 02 00 00 4f 1f 00 00 13 00 08 02 5b 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 ... >,
  size: 6880975,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  md5: '535c8576e1c94d169ea5a637487ee3b4',
  mv: [Function: mv] }
```

This is a fairly large excel document. Word Docs, pdfs, simple CSVs, etc also need to be possible for upload.

I've tried both node-postgres and sequelize libraries in a similar way:

```
app.post('/upload', async(req, res) => {
  var {upload} = req.files
  var data = upload.data
  console.log(data);
  const x = await pool.query(`insert into attachment (data, file_name, category) values (${data}, '${upload.name}', 'test')`)
  // Deconstruct x to get response values
  res.send("OK")
});
```

Some files like txt, plain csv files work and do upload however I receive errors such as
`error: invalid message format`
for excel or word files.

I've done something like this before with MongoDB but I can't switch databases. Another idea I had was to simply store the files on the production server in an 'uploads' files but I'm not sure that's good practice.

Any advice?

Comment: You trying to turn `data` into a string. Use query parameters to pass `data` as is. Is `data` a Buffer?

Comment: @Anatoly Yes it's a buffer. I'll look into those query parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using query parameters.

```
app.post('/upload', async(req, res) => {
  var {upload} = req.files
  var data = upload.data
  const x = await pool.query(`insert into attachment (data, file_name, category) values ($1, '${upload.name}', 'test')`, [data])
  res.send("OK")
});
```